# Left indentation of subsection headline

Tags: moderncv

I'm using moderncv package in LaTex to prepare my CV. I've been struggling on left indentation of subsection title. How would you push the \subsection header to the left?

As you see in the image, the **[Subsection 1]** is aligned along the vertical line where **[Section]** starts. How can I push the **[Subsection 1]** (blue substitle) to the left so that it's aligned with the line below **[Subsection 1.1:]** which starts with bullet?

[image]

Comment: In other words, is it possible to start the [Subsection 1] right below the blue line ?

Comment: A very warm welcome to TeX.SE!  If you post a minimal working example (a WME) it will make it easier for other people to help answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to redefine the `\subsection` command.

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Title}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \strut\subsectionstyle{#2}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\end{document}
```